# How to check a variable is number or not in UNIX

Tags: linux, unix

I a trying to check if a variable is number or not in UNIX as below:
when I execute the program its always going to else block.The regex is correct as I checked online testing tool

```
set reqex = '^[0-9]*$'
  if(  $parm  =~ $reqex ) then 
  echo "     ** NUMBER PASSED [$JOBPARM] **     "
  else 
  echo "     ** NOT NUMBER PASSED [$JOBPARM] **     " 
  endif
```

Comment: What scripting language are you using? You seem to be using some syntax from `csh` and some syntax from `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which shell or scripting language you are using.

If you are trying to develop a shell script for ksh or bash, this should work:

```
 reqex="^[0-9]+$"
 if [ $parm  =~ $reqex ]; then 
     echo "     ** NUMBER PASSED [$JOBPARM] **     "
 else 
     echo "     ** NOT NUMBER PASSED [$JOBPARM] **     " 
 fi
```

I've also made alight change to the regex. Instead of `*` matching zero or more digits, I'm using `+` for matching at least one digit.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: I changed * to + and set $parm to 123 but it throws gives me "not number passed" message. I am using Kshell. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you change from `*` to `+` ? In your script?